# Basic calculator script in UNIX - Want to make error messages disappear if no variables are entered

Tags: unix, error-handling, syntax-error, sh

Here is a basic script with getopt command and assigned variables.

If someone were to type in

```
MyScript -a
```

with no words or numbers added after the -a, then an error message would pop up! The same happens if you replace -a with any other assigned variables. If I wanted no error message to appear, how would I go about doing this?

Hints/advice is preferred over a simply strict answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) manual:

> `getopts` can report errors in two ways. If the first character of `optstring` is a colon, silent error reporting is used. In normal operation diagnostic messages are printed when invalid options or missing option arguments are encountered. If the variable `OPTERR` is set to 0, no error messages will be displayed, even if the first character of optstring is not a colon.

Since you tag the question with Unix and don't mention `bash`, you may or may not be so lucky, but the answer is to read the manual page carefully.

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to fix it eventually because of this answer!